# Is contemplation of death auto-suggestion?

Tags: death, contemplation

Is doing contemplation of death  auto-suggestion to meditate ? is it working on my subconsciousness ? maybe i should just do auto suggestion telling my self many times to meditate - maybe its more effective ?

can i do my own version of death contemplation or should i say exactly the words in the sutta ?  if i can what are the guidelines that i should follow when make my own version ?

If i dont fear death and dont care to die - is it still useful ?

can i do death contemplation about people i care about ?

you can only answer some questions i asked or add something i didnt ask about which is related and can be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Contemplating death achieves certain objectives and contemplation should be worded to realise the said objective though the wording can be different:

- being fearless at the moment of death such that your last mind moment can be conducive to a better rebirth - hence contemplate along the lines that everyone will die including me, death is common to all. Is this form you can use other people like famous people, great people, powerful people, etc. who have died to re enforce that achievements do not stop death. In addition you can perhaps use living loved ones so you reduce your attachment to them so you will be less saddened when they actually die if you are to die before hand you will be able to let go of loved ones.
- get the notion that time is running out hence attend to what needs attention without delay - hence contemplate along the lines that life is un certain, death is certain, hence be quick. This might be like auto suggestion to meditate. But auto suggestion to meditate will not achieve the same effectiveness as it does not embed the notion that time is limited, this limit is unknown and it is running out fast and death takes your ability to beat or win over death to achieve deathlessness. This notion fuels urgency and spiritual restlessness to practice. As a result this helps with eliminating or reducing procrastination.
- letting go of possession and loved ones - hence contemplate along the lines that when I die I will not take anything or anyone with me and no one has in the past.

In devising your own wording, keep it short, sweet / easy to mentally recite (rhyming / rhythmic), to the point, in a language you understand.

Also see: [How do I do "contemplation of death" meditation? And is it dangerous?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14363/how-do-i-do-contemplation-of-death-meditation-and-is-it-dangerous)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i appricate your answers about this subject -   my biggest trouble is procrastination and if this helps to deal with it than it would be great

Comment: Item 2 in the above list helps.

Answer (score 1):

Buddha used to send new disciples to cremation ground for few months to contemplate upon death. It does not matter what you do but make sure you have something which reminds of death. For example something you can wear, even an alarm on your phone. Humans are pretty evasive when it comes to death. Any form of reminder can make you aware of impending death and hence urgency to meditate. The whole point is create a situation for yourself which reminds you of death. But please do not be stressed by it.